# `PrintQueue.AddJob` does not finish

Tags: c#, .net, printing, windows-10

I tried following code on some PCs.

```
using (var lps = new LocalPrintServer())
using(var pqueue = lps.GetPrintQueue("PRINTER-NAME"))
{
    pqueue.AddJob("job-name", @"C:\example.xps", false, pticket);
}
```

On only one PC, it did not work.
The application froze at `AddJob` method.
It never finished even after waiting for long time.
There are no exceptions.

The PC where this problem occurred is Windows10 and applied CreatorsUpdate.
Other PCs are Windows7, Windows8.1 and Windows10 applied AnniversaryUpdate.

Is this problem a bug of CreatorsUpdate?

Supplement:
The PC which has CreatorsUpdate can print xps file by this code.

```
using (var lps = new LocalPrintServer())
using(var pqueue = lps.GetPrintQueue("PRINTER-NAME"))
using (var doc = new XpsDocument(@"C:\example.xps", System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
{
    var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(pqueue);
    var docSeq = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    writer.Write(doc, pticket);
}
```

Comment: I've run into the same problem.  It only happens on some machines, others seem fine.

Comment: I've found using AddJob to get a PrintSystemJobInfo object then streaming the XPS file to its JobStream is more reliable.

Comment: This might be an issue with Windows 10

Comment: @blz your codes save my life and it solves the printing issue on my machine

Comment: Doesn't the first parameter in writer.Write be the variable docSeq?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that the target printer driver is not XPS based. I had the same problem with that.

You may first check the compatibility of the printer through:

```
LocalPrintServer server = new LocalPrintServer(PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministrateServer);
PrintQueue queue = server.GetPrintQueue("MyPrinterName");            
MessageBox.Show(queue.IsXpsDevice.ToString());
```

If the result is false, then that's why.