# PrintQueue.AddJob() stops execution

Tags: c#, .net, windows, printing

I am trying to print an xps file with a local printer without any dialog. When I call PrintQueue.AddJob() the execution stops it doesn't go to the next line of code but it doesn't throw any exception and the programming keeps running.

The code I use:

```
LocalPrintServer lps = new LocalPrintServer();
PrintQueue pq = lps.GetPrintQueue("printQueueName");

pq.AddJob("jobName", pathToFile, false);
```

Thank you.

Comment: AddJob returns a PrintSystemJobInfo. Have you examined that?

Comment: That's the problem it won't fill that object because it won't execute any further it is stuck on addJob().

Comment: Same problem for me.  This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073755/printqueue-addjob-does-not-finish, which also doesn't have an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the same issue, but I only managed to find some workarounds. I tried to work around the issue by using the `CreateXpsDocumentWriter.Write` method, but that removed some page settings from my document (like Page Orientation per page).

Did find out that using `PrintQueueStream` works and keeps the page settings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueuestream

```
LocalPrintServer lps = new LocalPrintServer();
PrintQueue pq = lps.GetPrintQueue("printQueueName");

using (var fileStream = new StreamReader(pathToFile))
using (var printStream = new PrintQueueStream(pq, "jobName", true))
{
    fileStream.BaseStream.CopyTo(printStream);
}
```